# Apex Charts Timeline - Datalabels not syncro with tooltip and title

Tags: label, timeline, apexcharts

We are using ApexCharts Timeline.
We use series to show projects duration.
Everything seems to be ok but we have a problem width datalabel.

**Datalabels are not syncro with tooltip and title.**

The first series is ok ...

```
series: [
{
  name: "AMISOC",
  data: [
    {
      x: "Gestion des mesures d'intégration",
      y: [new Date("2020-06").getTime(), new Date("2021-06").getTime()],
    },
    {
      x: "Portefeuilles + validations - Stabilisation",
      y: [new Date("2020-06").getTime(), new Date("2021-06").getTime()],
    },
    {
      x: "Stat OFS AMIG - lot 3",
      y: [new Date("2020-06").getTime(), new Date("2021-04").getTime()],
    },
    {
      x: "Test 3  VZA",
      y: [new Date("2021-01").getTime(), new Date("2022-03").getTime()],
    }
  ]
},
{
  name: "FE",
  data: [
    {
      x: "Trafic des paiements (lot 2)",
      y: [new Date("2020-06").getTime(), new Date("2021-06").getTime()],
    }
  ]
},
{
  name: "IT",
  data: [
    {
      x: "Migration Windows et Outils bureautique",
      y: [new Date("2021-03").getTime(), new Date("2021-06").getTime()],
    },
    {
      x: "Upgrade technique Infrastucture 2021",
      y: [new Date("2021-01").getTime(), new Date("2021-12").getTime()],
    }
  ]
},
```

...

],

[serie OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA0aL.png)

but after the title are not following related title name.
It's ok in the tooltip but not in the dataLabel.

Does somebody sees what we are doing wrong?

[serie NOT SYNC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LProu.png)

Here is a Codepen: https://codepen.io/vinchoz/pen/rNjOKwv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find a working solution:

I replace this code

```
formatter: function (val, opt) {
  return opt.w.globals.labels[opt.dataPointIndex];
},
```

By this code

```
formatter: function(val,obj) {
    return obj.w.config.series[obj.seriesIndex].data[obj.dataPointIndex].x;
},
```

https://codepen.io/vinchoz/pen/oNBLOaB